# How to create a hasManyTrough Eloquent relationship in this database schema?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables

- products
- variants
- attributes
- options
- option_variant

Look at this sqlfiddle for details http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb1c73/24/0

Can I have something like this on my Product model to get all the attributes like I'm doing on the sqlfiddle query?

```
function attributes(){
return $this->hasManyThrough('Attributes','Variant');
}
```

THANKS!!
My Models:

```
<?php
class Product extends \Eloquent {
protected $table = 'products';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function variants()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Variant');

}

public function attributes(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Attribute','OptionVariant');
}
}
<?php
class Variant extends \Eloquent {
protected $table = 'variants';

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Product');

}

public function options()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Option');

}
}
<?php
class Attribute extends \Eloquent {
protected $table = 'attributes';

public function options()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Option');

}
}
<?php
class Option extends \Eloquent {
protected $table = 'options';

public function attribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Attribute');

}

public function variants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Variant');

}
}
<?php
class OptionVariant extends \Eloquent {
protected $table = 'option_variant';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want take all atributtes all time that you select the products:

In Product model:

```
$with = ['attributes'];
```

In Controller:

```
$products = $this->product->findAll();
return View::make('products.index', compact('products'));
```

In View:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
  {{ $product->attributes->column1 }}
@endforeach
```